# Return data in ionic app

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I linked the webservice with the app successfully and the data is retrieved but I can't access the data to display it or use it in any process.

```js
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public apiProvider: ApiProvider, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    this.usercheck = this.apiProvider.UserCheck();
    this.usercheck.subscribe(data => {console.log('my data: ', data); });
```

The result retrieved by the console.log is:

[image]

and I am using this code to display the data in ionic element.

```html
<ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let user of (usercheck|async)?.Array" (click)="openDetails(user)">
      {{ user.CinemaName }}
    </button>
  
  </ion-list>
```

but there is no result

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace below code

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public apiProvider: ApiProvider, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    this.usercheck = this.apiProvider.UserCheck();
    this.usercheck.subscribe(data => {console.log('my data: ', data); });
```

to

```
testData: any = [];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public apiProvider: ApiProvider, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
        this.usercheck = this.apiProvider.UserCheck();
        this.usercheck.subscribe(data => this.testData = data;);
```

And replace below code

```
<ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let user of (usercheck|async)?.Array" (click)="openDetails(user)">
      {{ user.CinemaName }}
    </button>

  </ion-list>
```

to

```
<ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let user of testData" (click)="openDetails(user)">
      {{ user.CinemaName }}
    </button>

  </ion-list>
```